# Core Data Relationships: How to insert a new object into an entity and create a relationship to an existing object in another entity

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I am building a little iPhone app which allows users to keep score of games they may be playing with friends. I now need to use relationships in Core Data but can't quite seem to get it working.

**I want to be able to add new data into one entity while creating a relationship to existing data in a different entity. How can I achieve this?**

*Please note I am new to Core Data and have spent the best part of today trying to figure this out but have run out of luck. Any help would be very much appreciated.*

---

I have 3 entities: **Scores**, **Games** and **Players**.

**Scores** Attributes: `date`, `player1Score`, `player2Score` and `status`.

**Games** Attributes: `title`.

**Players** Attributes: `name`.

I have many to many relationships between (**Scores** <<--->> **Games**) and (**Scores** <<--->> **Players**)

---

I already have a list of both games and players. The user selects which game and who is playing and with this information a set of objects is created in the **Scores** entity with relationships to the chosen game and players.

Here is my source:

```
//  Scores.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Games, Players;

@interface Scores : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * player1Score;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * player2Score;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * status;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *game;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *player;
@end

@interface Scores (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addGameObject:(Games *)value;
- (void)removeGameObject:(Games *)value;
- (void)addGame:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeGame:(NSSet *)values;

- (void)addPlayerObject:(Players *)value;
- (void)removePlayerObject:(Players *)value;
- (void)addPlayer:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removePlayer:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

---

```
// SC_ScoreViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SC_ScoreViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong) NSIndexPath *game;
@property (strong) NSIndexPath *playerOne;
@property (strong) NSIndexPath *playerTwo;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *playerOneName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *playerTwoName;

@end
```

---

```
//  SC_ScoreViewController.m

#import "SC_ScoreViewController.h"
#import "Scores.h"
#import "Players.h"
#import "Games.h"

@interface SC_ScoreViewController ()

@end

@implementation SC_ScoreViewController

@synthesize game;
@synthesize playerOne;
@synthesize playerTwo;

// managedObjectContext (context)
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Setup Nav Title
    self.navigationItem.title = [self.game valueForKey:@"title"];

    // Setup Player's Names
    [self.playerOneName setText:[self.playerOne valueForKey:@"name"]];
    [self.playerTwoName setText:[self.playerTwo valueForKey:@"name"]];


    Scores * newEntry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Scores"        inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    newEntry.player1Score = 0;
    newEntry.player2Score = 0;
    newEntry.status = nil;
    newEntry.player = self.playerOne; // Incompatible pointer types assigning to NSSet from NSIndexPath

    NSError *error;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @end
```

---

I hope I have been clear and provided enough information. This is my first question so I hope all is in order. Any help would be amazing, thank you.

Answer (score 9):

You have to insert `Players`' objects into `self.managedObjectContext` exactly the same as you insert a new `Score` object. It could be something like this:

```
Scores *score = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Scores" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
Player *player = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Player" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[score addPlayerObject:player];
```

You also have to change your relationship "Scores <<--->> Players" to be ordered, because right now you won't know which player is which. Other option here would be to use two many-to-one relationship (separately for player1 and player2).

One more thing: it's a best practice to name your entities in a singular form, so `Score`, instead of `Scores` and so on.

You should read [Creating Managed Object Relationships](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html). It's all nicely described in there.

<del>**UPDATE:** I think there shouldn't be a many-to-many relationship between Games and Scores (from what I understand Score can be renamed to Match). It probably should be a one-to-many relationship.</del>

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering so quickly. I have a couple of follow up questions if you don't mind. Looking at your code, a new player will be created along with the score, correct? If so my problem is that I already have players and want to link them to score, other wise i'm just recreating them. Also I have many to many relationships because scores can have multiple games and games can have multiple score, the same with players and scores.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your data model completely (your relationships). As for players, I see that you have `self.playerOne` and `self.playerOneName`. They're respectively of types: `NSIndexPath` and `UILabel`. When you operate on Core Data relationships you have to use `NSManagedObject`'s . I assumed that you don't have them yet (because they don't exist in your view controller), and that's why I created a new player with line: 'Player *player = [NSEntityDescription (...)'.

Comment: I have tried using NSManagedObject but couldn't get it working. I kept getting the error "Incompatible pointer types assigning to NSSet from NSManageObject". I feel like I'm missing something here, what line of code do I need to create my relationship from Scores to Players? Should I be using two separate relationships for each player?

Comment: You get this error, because `addPlayer:` expects `NSSet`, but you try to assign to it `NSManagedObject`. `addPlayerObject:` expects a single `NSManagedObject`. As I've written in my answer, you can either change your relationship to be ordered (then you would get `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSOrderedSet *players;`) or use two many-to-one relationships.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider re-designing your object graph. From reality, I have a concept in my head of how games, players, and scores relate to one another. Your object graph, however, doesn't seem to match that concept (but your concept of how games, players, and scores relate to each other may be different than mine).

I would eliminate all those many-to-many relationships and replace them with one-to-many relationships. For example, a player can have many scores, but a score wouldn't have many players. Three players might have a score of 100, but that doesn't mean they share a single score object (with the value of 100).

Here's how I might design the object graph:

Game entity:

- title attribute (e.g., "Monopoly")
- players relationship, one-to-many (one game, many players)

Player entity:

- name attribute (e.g., Joe Smith)
- games relationship, one-to-many (one player, many games)
- scores relationship, one-to-many (one player, many scores)

Score entity:

- score attribute, int value (e.g., 100)
- game relationship, one-to-one (one score, one game)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think of it when designing your model is as follows:

Game - is an object representing the type of game (monopoly, tennis, etc)

Match - the actual 'game', which takes place at a point in time and has an attribute like date/time or period. Plus player1, player2, etc... Whoever actually took part. Plus each team or players score e.g. player1Score, player2Score...

Competitor - or player.